# jQuery Selector Containing the Term "javascript:"

Tags: jquery-selectors

If I have an anchor tag like so:

```
<A id=rgVistaRequestIssues_ctl00_ctl02_ctl03_CancelButton 
href="javascript:__doPostBack('rgGridIssues$ctl00$ctl02$ctl03$CancelButton','')">
Cancel</A>
```

And I'd like to select just this anchor tag, I assumed this would work fine:

```
$('a[href^="javascript:"]').click(function () { selected = true; });
```

But it's not working at all.

What did work was:

```
$('a[href:contains("Cancel")]').click(function () { selected = true; });
```

But that's not specific enough for my tastes.

Is there some reason that the selector cannot find the term "javascript:" at runtime?  Does that get resolved before the selector has a chance to find it?

Thanks.

Comment: It works fine in FireFox.  What browser were you using?  Here is the an example for testing. http://jsfiddle.net/UXuAC/1

Comment: @JohnHartsock looks like it's also working in Chrome

Comment: Note: you did not put quotes around the id in your HTML.  I highly doubt this is the problem but it could be for whatever browser you are receiving the error in.

Comment: And works in IE9 (in IE7, 8 and 9 modes) too. Also working with all versions of jQuery, so I think it must a problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: IE9 (but would be relevant for IE7+)

Comment: @beaudetious - Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: First off... thanks for showing me jsFiddle.  Awesome tool.  Second... no I cannot reproduce my problem in jsFiddle.  I suspect it's got something to with how Telerik renders its HTML output.  We don't control how attributes are quoted or not quoted, for example.  I have another selector like this $('a[href^=mailto]') which fires correctly.  But not any of the selector's I tried where the href attribute starts with "javascript:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it worked for `:contains("Cancel")`, the most likely cause of it not firing is if the JavaScript was added dynamically by Telerik *after the page loads*.

In that case using a *delegated event handler*, attached to a non-changing ancestor will fix it.

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="javascript:"]', function () { selected = true; });
```

It works by listening for the event (click) to bubble up to a non-changing ancestor (`document` is the default is nothing else is closer/convenient). It *then* applies the selector to the elements in the bubble-chain. It *then* runs the function against *any matching elements that caused the event*. This only requires the selector to exist at *event time*, not when the event was registered.

Delegated events have a faster connect time (as they only connect a handler to one element) and any minuscule delay added at event time will be unnoticed as you simply cannot click the mouse fast enough for it to show :)

Note: Do not use `'body'` for delegated events as it has a bug related to styling that may cause mouse events to not bubble to `body` (if the calculated height of body is 0).